# How to set RibbonToolTip as global Tooltip

Tags: wpf, tooltip, ribbon

I want to use RibbonToolTip outside the Ribbon for TextBox.

The long way is:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
  <TextBox.ToolTip>
    <RibbonToolTip Title="{DynamicResource nameTitle}" Description="{DynamicResource nameDescription}"/>
  </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

I want to use something like this instead

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTipTitle="{DynamicResource nameTitle}" ToolTipDescription="{DynamicResource nameDescription}"/>
```

I can set the RibbonToolTip with

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
    <Setter.Value>
      <RibbonToolTip/>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

but how to set Title and Description.

Is there any way without deriving a new class from TextBox to create new dependency objects for ToolTipTitle and ToolTipDescription?

```
<TextBox ToolTip.Title="Name" ...
```

does also not work because ToolTip is not typed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is attached properties.

```
public class ExToolTip : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Title", typeof(string), typeof(ExToolTip), new PropertyMetadata("", OnTitleChanged));

        public static string GetTitle(DependencyObject o)
        {
            return (string)o.GetValue(TitleProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTitle(DependencyObject o, string value)
        {
            o.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnTitleChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement fe = o as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe != null)
            {
                if (fe.ToolTip == null)
                {
                    fe.ToolTip = new RibbonToolTip();

                }
                RibbonToolTip rtt = fe.ToolTip as RibbonToolTip;
                if (rtt != null)
                {
                    rtt.Title = (string)e.NewValue;
                }
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Description", typeof(string), typeof(ExToolTip), new PropertyMetadata("", OnDescriptionChanged));

        public static string GetDescription(DependencyObject o)
        {
            return (string)o.GetValue(DescriptionProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDescription(DependencyObject o, string value)
        {
            o.SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnDescriptionChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement fe = o as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe != null)
            {
                if (fe.ToolTip == null)
                {
                    fe.ToolTip = new RibbonToolTip();

                }
                RibbonToolTip rtt = fe.ToolTip as RibbonToolTip;
                if (rtt != null)
                {
                    rtt.Description = (string)e.NewValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

With this class I can easily write:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" ExToolTip.Title="title" ExToolTip.Description="Description" />
```